# How to use a void* in C++ to hold the value of an uint32_t when the pointer is passed as a reference to a method

Tags: c++, pointers, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am having issues storing values into a void* and successfully retrieving what I stored in initially. The below is my pseudo code/train of thought:

Inside method 1 on a client

```
StatusCode doSomething() {
    string filename = "somefile.txt";
    void* server_checksum;

    //Stat signature (string &filename, void* file_status)
    StatusCode fileStatus = Stat(filename, &server_checksum); //Passing the address of the pointer

    //We received the fileStatus from Stat, I expect the value of server_checksum to match what the server sent
    //However, this prints a completely different number, and I do not know how to ensure it holds the right value
    cout << *((uint32_t *)serverCrc) << endl; 

    return StatusCode::OK;
}
```

Inside the Stat method on the client, there's a protobuf via grpc that has the checksum for the file on the server:

```
StatusCode Stat(string &filename, void* file_status) {
    //call the grpc method on the server (abstracted)
    .
    .
    .
    //Contains the checksum of the file on the server - this works fine
    uint32_t s_crc = response.server_crc(); 

    // I print it in both the server and the client to confirm it is the same value - this works fine
    cout << s_crc << endl; 

    //In my understanding, here I am assigning the value of s_crc to the void * file status, which I passed the address for inside of method 1 - this works fine
    file_status = (uint32_t *) &s_crc; 

    // I print file_status to make sure it still matches the value the server sent - this works fine
    cout<<"file_status " << *((uint32_t *)file_status) << endl; 

    return StatusCode::OK; -> Continues inside method 1 above
}
```

Comment: Why are you messing around with `void*` here?  Just pass a `uint32_t&` and assign to that.  `void*` has its place, but this doesn't seem like it unless there's some constraint you've not mentioned.

Comment: Hi Miles, are you referring to `void* server_checksum`? Suggesting that I define it as `uint32_t * server_checksum` and call stat like `(filename, &server_checksum)`?

Comment: No, I'm saying you should declare your `Stat` function as something like `StatusCode Stat(const std::string& filename, uint32_t& file_status)` and call it as `uint32_t file_status; Stat(filename, file_status);`.  There's absolutely no reason to use a `void*` at all here.

Comment: `&s_crc` takes the address of a local variable! Dereferencing it after `Stat` returns is going to give you garbage.

Comment: *I am having issues storing values into a `void*` and successfully retrieving what I stored in initially.* Common problem and a good reason not to use pointers to `void`. The only time `void*` should show up in C++ code is when you need to call a C-style API.

Comment: The constraint is that I cannot change the Stat signature, sadly

Comment: @CjRobin That is very important information to include in the question. Kind-of late at this point, but remember to state the requirements in your future questions. It helps keep the noise down by focusing everyone on the task at hand, "Help me write bad code as good as possible", and not load you up with "Do this instead" answers.

Comment: Noted - I appreciate both of you guys' answers, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no reason to use a `void*` here at all.  C++ has a type system; you should use it.

Instead of declaring your out parameter as a `void*`, declare it to be either a pointer or reference to the type you want to write.  In this case that appears to be `uint32_t`:

```
StatusCode Stat(const std::string& filename, uint32_t& file_status) {
    //call the grpc method on the server (abstracted)
    // ...

    //Contains the checksum of the file on the server - this works fine
    file_status = response.server_crc();

    return StatusCode::OK;
}
```

And then you can call it without doing any special gymnastics:

```
StatusCode doSomething() {
    std::string filename = "somefile.txt";
    uint32_t server_checksum;

    StatusCode fileStatus = Stat(filename, server_checksum);

    std::cout << server_checksum << std::endl;

    return StatusCode::OK;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86f01a2e76aa6892)

---

If there's some reason you *must* use a `void*` and thus explicitly give up the protections offered by the type system then the pointer still has to point *to something*.  In the end the code will look very similar, just with an extra cast and significantly more opportunity to mess up and wander into the realm of undefined behavior:

```
StatusCode Stat(const std::string& filename, void* file_status) {
    //call the grpc method on the server (abstracted)
    // ...

    // cast to the appropriate pointer type
    uint32_t* status_ptr = static_cast<uint32_t*>(file_status);

    // now write the status to the object pointed to by the pointer passed to us
    *status_ptr = response.server_crc();

    return StatusCode::OK;
}
```

Not much extra is needed when calling the function, since any pointer-to-object type can be implicitly converted to `void*`:

```
StatusCode doSomething() {
    std::string filename = "somefile.txt";
    uint32_t server_checksum;

    StatusCode fileStatus = Stat(filename, &server_checksum);

    std::cout << server_checksum << std::endl;

    return StatusCode::OK;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/194b1f7e32215c8e)

Comment: This is an excellent response. It finally works locally for me, thank you, Miles!